# mysqlp - LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILES returns 0 rows affected

Tags: mysql

I did

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/username/enrolled_courses.csv' INTO TABLE courses_taken FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

I end up receiving this feedback from the MySQL server:

> Query OK, 0 rows affected, 58575 warnings (0.03 sec)
> Records: 19438  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 19438  Warnings: 58575

How do I fix this issue and successfully import the CSV file into the desired table?

[image]

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Your file is already local - remove LOCAL keyword from the query. Check `local_infile` and `secure_file_priv` system variables values and `FILE` privilege. View warnings produced by the query (I see 3 warnings per imported row). Show first 3-5 rows of imported file and CREATE TABLE script of the destination table. Verify the table structure (the column cannot be NOT NULL and DEFAULT NULL at the same time).